# how to set image name which we are saving in document directory

Tags: ios

i am getting image from gallery now that image is getting displayed in application but same time i want to save that image in document directory

for that i am using below code

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    selectImage.image = image;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                      [NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

now my question is you can see that i gave name as test.png but i want to set name of actual image. so every time user select different image and different name get stored

so how can i set actual name of image in path

plz help thank you :)

Comment: when you select the image at that time take image name as a string and pass that string in the place of test.png then it'l works fine.

Comment: thats the question how to get image name?

Comment: are you getting the images in the form of urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following code to get new name every time to store your image

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

Get document directory Path

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Grab the content Directory, all the files at location

```
NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] error:&error];
```

Now get count of number of resources, and create new file name by adding 1 to current Count

```
NSString *newFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test_%d.png",[contents count]+1];
```

Comment: This logic is not globle. suppose you have 4 image. then last image will be Test_5.png. if you delete Test_4.png.and then add new image it cant be add because according to your logic it will be Test_5.png.the duplicate will occur

Comment: Code posted here are for reference only, not complete code is posted, its for help not whole work @M.S.B

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below two lines to get the image name....may be it will use full for you..

```
NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

NSString *imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

   NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

 NSString *originalImg = [imagePath lastPathComponent];

}
```